# Explanation of HHL Cirq implementation

Tags: hhl-algorithm, cirq

Can someone help me in understanding the program on the link given below?
I would really appreciate if someone could give a detailed explanation ...

https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/examples/hhl.py

Comment: What part of that program don't you understand specifically?

Comment: Actually, I get nothing from it. @VictoryOmole

Comment: What parts of the docstring at the top of that file don't you understand?

Comment: I understand the basic flow of algorithm. Subroutines are mentioned, but i don't get how those subroutines are implemented @VictoryOmole

Comment: Please try to formulate your question to become comprehensible and answerable even if the remote link goes down.